# How can I get a value of 0 for records that don't satisfy the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple SELECT statement, in t-sql:

```
SELECT Category, count(Category) as Total 
FROM mytable 
WHERE gender='F'
GROUP BY Category
```

Which gives me

```
Category     Total
make up       10
```

This if fine, but I also have a `Class_B` category. `Class_B` is made up only of `gender=M`.  So, although there is no `Class_B` and I'm not matching any records, I would regardless like the returned table to be like:

```
Category     Total
make up       10
shaving kit   0
```

Any advice would be appreciate.

*EDIT:*  major update to make this more clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: are you looking for `HAVING`? `Select count(*) GROUP BY a.field HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`

Comment: where do you store Class_B category? you need to left join that table with myTable

Comment: sorry all, I had to edit the question to make it clear what I'm after. My apologies.

Comment: Man it was like a downvote party in here last night... and with no explanations! imagine that.

Answer (score 2):

From your original query:

```
SELECT Category, count(Category) as Total 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Category
```

**all** categories that exist in the table would be represented.  What you would actually need is a `join` on a table that actually contains all your potential categories.  Something to the affect of:

```
SELECT c.category, count(m.*) as total
from categories c
left join myTable m on c.categoryId = m.categoryId
group by c.category
```

I'm a bit unclear based on your edits... but this might work

```
select m.category, isnull(subQuery.total, 0)
  from mytable m
  left join (
    select category, count(1) as total
    from mytable
    where gender = 'f'
    group by category
    ) subQuery on m.category = subQuery.category
  group by m.category, subQuery.total
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b0a9/15

Comment: I'm sorry -- I had written the question poorly. I've since edited.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
; WITH FullCategory AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Category
    FROM mytable
), FemaleCategoryCount AS (
    SELECT Category, count(Category) as Total 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE gender='F'
    GROUP BY Category 
)
SELECT fc.Category, COALESCE(fcc.Total, 0) Total
FROM FullCategory fc
LEFT JOIN FemaleCategoryCount fcc
    ON fc.Category = fcc.Category
```

Comment: @Blam, I'm not sure your answer would be faster... and also, I believe your answer is incorrect. You'd be counting duplicates.

Comment: Just uncomment your code at the bottom and run it for yourself. ;)

Comment: Come on, why is an answer with working sqlfiddle getting voted down?

Answer (score 0):

if you can add in what makes the row unique this might work

```
SELECT t1.Category, count(distinct(t2.name)) as Total 
  FROM mytable t1 
  left join mytable t2  
    on t2.category = t1.category 
   and t2.gender='F'
 GROUP BY t1.Category
```

Comment: I think you'll get a whole lot of duplicates with this.... wouldn't you? In other words... the count would be off.

Comment: @samyi Deplicates?  Just how in the world would you bet a duplicate on group by.  It works.

Comment: Not trying to pick fights... just trying to get to the answer.. ;)

Comment: @samyi OK I gave you a +1

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple and efficient way of doing it.

```
SELECT  Category, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN gender='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Category
```